# How to define relationships while using a single foreign key for multiple tables (EF-core)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I'm using a single foreign key which refers multiple tables (based on item type in the below example) and trying to define one-many relation (Ef-Core). I need to define a relationship (using modelBuilder) based on ItemType (If Item type is CARD define relation between Tracking and Card and so on)

```
class Tracking
{
    int TrackingId;

    [Foreignkey]
    int ItemId;

    ItemType itemType {get; set;}

    virtual Card card {get; set;}

    virtual GiftCard card {get; set;}
}

enum ItemType
{
    CARD,
    GIFTCARD,
    PASSBOOK
}

class Card
{

    int Id;

    virtual ICollection<Tracking> Tracking {get; set;}
    //other properties
}

class GiftCard
{
    int Id;

    virtual ICollection<Tracking> Tracking {get; set;}
     //other Properties
}
```

I'm kind of new to this framework. Thought of using a composite key by introducing another key but I'm not allowed to add new keys.

Comment: What do you mean that you aren't allowed to add new keys? Are you saying that you aren't allowed to add any new tables?

Comment: I'm not allowed to add any new keys in the existing tables

Comment: How about a unique constraint?

Comment: Could you please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to solve it.

```
class Tracking
{
    int TrackingId;

    [Foreignkey]
    int? CardId;

    [Foreignkey]
    int? GiftCardId;

    [Foreignkey]
    int? PassBookId;

    virtual Card? card {get; set;}

    virtual GiftCard? card {get; set;}
}
```

So now you can add extra Foreign key. You need to use `int?` instead of `int` so the relationship is optional, thus `Tracking` entity can be attached to different parent as per needed.

Comment: But is there any other way to do it without adding extra foreign keys. I just want to know if it's possible to implement it with a single foreign key (ItemId)

Comment: Is there any way to use the Enum (ItemType) for defining relationship between 'Tracking' and 'Items' (Card, GiftCard, Passbook etc).

Comment: It is a very interesting concept, however I don't really think it is possible..